# Mirth: cannot execute database query

Tags: mysql, mirth

My problem is: if I change the query string below to `select * from table;`, it works fine. but if I execute the query string below, it throws an error:

```
SQL error: Invalid column number. Cannot less than or equal zero.
```

This is the code:

```
columnHeader = " 'id', 'pat_name', 'pat_age' ";
var filename = $('serType') + $('serId') + ".csv"; 

    var reporting_exportQuery = "select " + columnHeader + 
                        " union all " + 
                        "select * " +
                        "from " + $('serType') + 
                        " into outfile 'C://mytest/reports/service reports/"+$('serType') + "/" + "" + filename + "' " +
                        "fields terminated by ',' " +
                        "lines terminated by '\\n';";           

    var test = "select * from Age;";
    reporting_DBConn = DatabaseConnectionFactory.createDatabaseConnection('com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',:D);  
    logger.info(reporting_exportQuery);
    var result = reporting_DBConn.executeCachedQuery(reporting_exportQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is `columnHeader` have a diferent number of columns than `select *` in the union part.

Step to debug.

- print the result string `reporting_exportQuery`
- try running that string on the MySql.

**Added**:

- First Select doesn't have `FROM` part

.

```
 var reporting_exportQuery = 
             "select " + columnHeader + 
             "FROM SomeTable"    <--- need FROM
             " union all " + 
             "select " + columnHeader + <--- need same columns
```

Comment: Nope, I tried the actual columns inside my query string and it doesn't work as well..

Comment: I mean the problem isnt the `mirth` part, The problem is the sql. First select doesnt have `FROM` part. Also simply the mySQL query when you ask a question, Remove the `into outfile` when you are testing the query to make sure you are getting the data.

Comment: I tried your solution before, with my original query string. I printed my query string to mirth's log panel, then executed it in MySQL workbench. And it worked fine. But the problem has been resolved because I found a completely different solution.

Comment: Then please share your solution. Maybe will help another person in the future.

Comment: I would try as soon as I have time!

Answer (score 0):

You are adding(union) one column `columnHeader` with all columns (*) from table. You can do like this

```
SELECT 'columnHeader',table_alias.* FROM TABLE table_alias...


var filename = $('serType') + $('serId') + ".csv"; 

var reporting_exportQuery = 
                    "select 'columnHeader',table_alias.* " +
                    "from " + $('serType') table_alias+ 
                    " into outfile 'C://mytest/reports/service reports/"+$('serType') + "/" + "" + filename + "' " +
                    "fields terminated by ',' " +
                    "lines terminated by '\\n';";           

var test = "select * from Age;";
reporting_DBConn = DatabaseConnectionFactory.createDatabaseConnection('com.mysql.jdbc.Driver','jdbc:mysql://localhost:3310/cnwlreports', :D);  
logger.info(reporting_exportQuery);
var result = reporting_DBConn.executeCachedQuery(reporting_exportQuery);
```